# Jquery function to toggle all radio buttons on the page as

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

The question sums it up ... Here's what I've tried, is there a better way? It works once (selects and deselects once) then stops working ...

> ```
> <a href="#resources" onclick="$(':radio').each(function(){$(this).attr('checked', true); });">(Select All)</a>
> <a href="#resources" onclick="$(':radio').each(function(){$(this).attr('checked', false); });">(Deselect All)</a>
> ```

Comment: What you have works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/qc68zrh3/ Just assign it to a button press.

Answer (score 2):

For stuff like this, I recommend:

```
$('input:radio').each(function() { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
$('input:radio').each(function() { $(this).prop('checked', true); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#selectAll").click(function() { $('input:radio').prop('checked', true);  });

$("#deselectAll").click(function() { $('input:radio').prop('checked', false); });
```

No need to use `.each` function, since jQuery uses implicit iteration anyway. Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc68zrh3/21/)