# How can I switch all radioboxes on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a radio boxes column ("Yes"/"No").

The challenge is to create a button that will switch all radio boxes to "Yes" or "No" depending on which value they have at the moment of the click.

How I can connect different groups of radio boxes with each other? 
I've done similar tasks before but with checkboxes. With them, you need simply switch between `checked, true` and `checked, false`.

I came across this answer: [Jquery function to toggle all radio buttons on the page as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334642/jquery-function-to-toggle-all-radio-buttons-on-the-page-as) but they have two buttons and I have only one.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
$('.select-deselect-all').on('click', function() {
  var radios = $('tbody.table-body').find('input[type=radio]')
  $(radios).each(function() {
$(this).hasClass('checked') ? $(this).prop('checked', true) : $(this).prop('checked', false)
  })
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn select-deselect-all">
    Select/deselect all
</button>
<br> 
<table id="articles_table" class="table no-highlight">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Article number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Commodity code</th>
      <th class="table-radio-column">Request Supplier Declaration?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="1_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="1" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='1_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="1_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="1" value="No">
          <label for='1_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="2_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="2" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='2_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="2_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="2" value="No">
          <label for='2_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="3_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="3" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='3_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="3_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="3" value="No">
          <label for='3_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

It's working properly with the following code:

```
$('.select-deselect-all').on('click', function() {
  $('td input[type=radio]').each(function() {  
    if($(this).prop('checked') || $(this).attr('checked')) {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
       $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
       $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
  })
})
```

**But there is a bug when you only one or two articles and later press the button "Select/Deselect" multiple times.
What could be the reason for such radio boxes behavior?** 
Does anybody know how to deal with radio buttons?

Comment: You shouldn't reject an edit, take its content, and then apply your edit. In the future, accept the edit (as long as it isn't destructive or breaking any of the rules) and then apply your edit.

Comment: sorry, but I'm quite new to StackOverflow 
maybe an edit was rejected by accident, can you make it again?
I'm very sorry ;(

Comment: Don't worry about it, we all have to learn somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue (this function switches groups of 2 radiobuttons between each other):

```
$('.select-deselect-all').on('click', function() {
    var radio = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').first().val();
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== radio) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was working on click too, instead of checked... works great with click :) ..upvote for solution

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using prop and attr to check and uncheck

1. Loop all radio buttons with .each method
2. Check with both `prop('checked')` and `attr('checked')` for checked, as using either one of them will work only once and fail other times
3. Similarly check and uncheck radio buttons using both `prop()` and `attr()`

Radio button toggling is not possible with prop and attr ,
please refer this link-https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs  for more details and default behaviour of radio button

```js
$('.select-deselect-all').on('click', function() {
  $('td input[type=radio]').each(function() {  
    if($(this).prop('checked') || $(this).attr('checked')) {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
       $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
       $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn select-deselect-all">
    Select/deselect all
</button>
<br> 
<table id="articles_table" class="table no-highlight">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Article number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Commodity code</th>
      <th class="table-radio-column">Request Supplier Declaration?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="1_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="1" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='1_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="1_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="1" value="No">
          <label for='1_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="2_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="2" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='2_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="2_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="2" value="No">
          <label for='2_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="article-number">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="table-radio-column">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="3_YES" class="request-article-choice" name="3" value="Yes" checked>
          <label for='3_YES'>Yes</label>

          <input type="radio" id="3_NO" class="request-article-choice ml-20" name="3" value="No">
          <label for='3_NO' class="ml-20">No</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

codepen -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ewxKxQ?editors=1010

Comment: thank you very much for your solution, it works properly :)

but there is a little bug: try to select 1 or 2 radio buttons and then click the button

Comment: @Karen, as it select All or Deselect All, it resets all buttons to either select All Yes or All No, and it is not toggling the Yes or No? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: please select 1st "Yes" and press the button several times, you'll understand what I mean :)

Comment: @Karen, i just created custom radio buttons to have control on toggling - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BgbqqL  Hope it works for you :)

Comment: thank you for your efforts, but my app works only with radiobuttons(


I will try to adapt your previous solution with radios, thank you:)

Comment: @Karen, I m checking on that issue with my previous solution

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it: you iterate over the `table-radio-columns`, not each radio button, then for each of those, each of the radio buttons within it. Then just switch the checked one to unchecked and the unchecked one to checked. Note that the values don't really matter here: every one of those columns has two radios, one of which will be checked and one of which will be unchecked, so you just need to toggle them.

Been a very long while since I used jQuery, but possible pseudocode solution (I think the methods sketched out are correct, but as I say it's been a while, so there may be a more compact/better solution using the jQuery API that I've forgotten):

```
$(columns).each(column => {
  $(radios).each(radio => {
    radio.toggleClass('checked')
    radio.hasClass('checked') ? radio.prop('checked', true) : radio.prop('checked', false)
  })
})
```

Comment: Your way is deselecting "Yes" radio buttons, but not selecting "No" radios, I've updated the snippet

Comment: I think that there should be smth connected to the value, cause we have 2 checkboxes with the same name